# Launch Universal App Store using C++ code

Tags: c++, winapi, microsoft-metro

I need to launch Universal app store using C++ code. I tried launching them by passing `AppUserModelId` in `IApplicationActivationManager->ActivateApplication`.
Is there any other way to launch metro apps instead of using `IApplicationActivationManager`?

The code is:

```
CComPtr<IApplicationActivationManager> spAppActivationManager;
HRESULT hrResult = E_INVALIDARG;
if (wcslen(pcwzAppUserModelId) > 0)
{
    hrResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IApplicationActivationManager, (LPVOID*)&spAppActivationManager);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hrResult))
    {
        hrResult = CoAllowSetForegroundWindow(spAppActivationManager, NULL);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hrResult))
        {
            hrResult = spAppActivationManager->ActivateApplication(pcwzAppUserModelId, NULL, AO_NONE, pdwProcessId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I read this, you've got a method that works. So what is the problem?

Comment: How do you use this method ? Show us code. And what is the return value of the method ? You can use this link to quickly see the meaning of an error code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The problem is with App user model Id, I want to make my program compatible with Win 8 and Win 10, also I am not able to get its value from registry.

Comment: @mikedu95: There are better ways to turn an `HRESULT` into a human-readable representation. Visual Studio comes with a handy error lookup tool (*Tools* -> *Error Lookup*). Even more convenient: By appending `,hr` to a variable/value in a *Watch* window, you get live feedback as you're debugging.

Comment: @user5571918 show us your code

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand how the system works and you want to make the system fit into your mental model. That's the wrong way to approach this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you please guide me the right approach then.